# What log shall I explore to discover cause of "Couldn't Generate PGP Key"?

Tags: 12.10, log, pgp

While attempting to join the U+1 and download the code of conduct I followed the instructions on generating a public key and received the subj message.

```
Ubuntu 12.10 
Gnome session fall back 
chromium browser 
Dell Inspiron 6000 laptop 
Intel celeron 1.5 Ghz 
2 Gb mem 
40 Gb HDD
```

Thanks in advance
Pete

Comment: this old laptop failed to run programs after the above occurrence (I left it on overnight in sleep mode). Upon reboot the hard disk repaired itself (after I chose f.) reboot enabled the other programs to run.

Comment: Using my up-to-date desktop I was successful, but I'd like to explore the issue on laptop